# Comparison date format CURRENT from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have small problem with my code. I insert DATE to database as "08-01-2016" (Day-Month-Year) and I must compare Current date with data from row.

My SQL code is:

```
WHERE date_from = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

But this doesn't work...
Anybody can help me build good query to do this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ohh! Sorry for problem! I don't know why but I write wrong code before :( Good code is:

```
date_from = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Sorry and thanks!